# git merge again after merge and commit?

Tags: git, github, merge

Needing to manually merge a pull request, I followed github's instructions:
Step 1: From your project repository, bring in the changes and test.
`git fetch origin`
`git checkout -b featureBranch origin/featureBranch`
`git merge develop`
This resulted in 3 conflicts. I ran `git mergetool <filename>` on all three files and resolved the conflicts. No problems.
With no further conflicts, I committed the changes. I did not push yet.
A colleague pointed out that I incorrectly merged one file. Due to the amount of time it took to merge the conflicts, I'd prefer to merge develop with the newly merged file instead of resetting and redoing the entire merge.
However when I run `git mergetool develop <file>` git bash returns `No files need merging` which is also expected, but not what I want.
`git diff develop <file>` shows there are differences, also expected.
Is it possible to re-merge develop into my feature branch?

Comment: "No problems. With no further conflicts, I committed the changes" Are you positive that you remembered to *add* before commiting? Just checking.

Comment: @RomainValeri: `git mergetool` does the `git add` for you, after the merge tool itself exits and reports "file successfully merged".

Comment: @torek Oh, right, I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `git mergetool` command depends on the existence of the conflicted state.  Resolving a file removes the conflicted state, which is how `git mergetool` knows that the file is now merged.  That lets you merge some files, quit entirely out of mergetool, and run mergetool again and pick up where you left off.  But it means that when you allow `git mergetool` to mark the file as "resolved", that's it for that file.

If you have not finished and committed the merge—i.e., have not yet run `git merge --continue` or `git commit`—it is possible to restore a file to its unmerged state.<sup>1</sup>  There is a big caveat here—this wipes out the work you did to merge it so far (so *save the file elsewhere first!*)—and of course doesn't apply in your case anyway because you did finish the merge.

This means you *can't* use `git mergetool` itself to fix the problem—at least, not without repeating the merge.

You have multiple options here, because Git is a set of tools, not a solution.  Here are two:

1. Save the merge result.  Well, you automatically do this: it's in a *commit*.  Save the *commit hash ID* somewhere, typically by creating a branch or tag name now to remember it.  You could write it down on paper but copying a hash ID by hand is way too hard.  You could save it in a file ... but that's what `git tag` and `git branch` do, so why not use one of those?

   ```
   git tag saved-result
   ```

   Then, wipe out the merge, with `git reset --hard` back to the pre-merge state.  Re-run the merge.  Use the saved *commit* to get correctly merged files:

   ```
   git reset --hard HEAD~1
   git merge otherbranch

   git checkout saved-result -- file1.ext file2.ext
   ```

   These two files are now marked as resolved, ready to go into the new merge commit you'll make.

   Use the saved commit to get, for viewing purposes, you previous merge attempt that went wrong:

   ```
   git show saved-result:file3.ext > file3.ext.previous-merge-attempt
   ```

   Now run `git mergetool` or whatever you like to do, to work on file3.

   When you're all done, delete the branch or tag name you used:

   ```
   git tag -d saved-result
   ```

   for instance.
2. Using the merge result you have now, open the incorrectly merged file.  Find the incorrectly merged result and change it.  If you want to view the two or three inputs from before, you can get those:

   ```
   git show HEAD^1:file3.ext > file3.ext.ours
   git show HEAD^2:file3.ext > file3.ext.theirs
   ```

   Getting the merge base version of `file3.ext` is a little trickier:

   ```
   git merge-base --all HEAD^1 HEAD^2
   ```

   This should print out one hash ID.  If it prints more than one, you had a *recursive merge*.  Assuming you didn't, cut-and-paste the hash ID this just printed:

   ```
   git show <hash>:file3.ext > file3.ext.base
   ```

   You now have all three input files—the ones your merge tool would have seen—but not Git's attempt at merging.  If you want to get Git to show you what it put in for conflicts, use `git merge-file` like this:

   ```
   cp file3.ext.ours file3.ext.conflicted
   git merge-file file3.ext.conflicted file3.ext.base file3.ext.theirs
   ```

   You now have all four of the files.  Open the file(s) in whatever viewer(s) and/or editor(s) you like, fix the `file.ext` version, and write it out, and then replace the existing merge commit with a new merge commit made using the updated file:

   ```
   git add file3.ext
   git commit --amend
   ```

   (The existing merge commit continues to exist in your repository, and will be there for at least 30 days by default, but you won't *see* it unless you go looking in reflogs.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This isn't useful here, but we might as well say how to do it: use `git checkout -m` on the file, e.g., `git checkout -m -- path/to/file.ext`.  This erases the slot-zero entry and puts back the slot-1, slot-2, and slot-3 entries in Git's index, while also re-creating the merge conflicts in the work-tree copy of the file.

Note that `git checkout -m` on a *commit*, when *not* in the middle of a conflicted merge does something entirely different!